# mysql: compare integers with strings and return true

Tags: mysql

Is there any operator equivalent to `===` in MySQL which checks value as well the datatype?

I have a `u_id` field in a database which is **int** datatype

now from login page where user enter user id and during logicheck I write below code

```
$loginCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[userCode]);
$sql=SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE u_id=".$loginCode ;
$result=$db->query($sql);
```

This returns a row

now when enter **2.0** then it also return the row which I don't want, what I need is when 2.0 is written, query does not return any row.

`gettype($loginCode)` return string....

it's strange how a integer type(u_id) field can compare with string type in mysql?
Please suggest me solution or any better way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All SQL databases will implicitly convert a float to an int.

You could ensure that your login code contains nothing but numbers with a regular expresison.  For example:

```
WHERE u_id = <LoginCode> AND <LoginCode> RLIKE '^[0-9]+$'
```

Comment: there in not LoginCode, its `$loginCode`  how do i add php varaiable inside <>

Comment: `$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE u_id=".$loginCode." AND '".$loginCode."' RLIKE '^[0-9]+$'";`

Answer (score 3):

you can cast your data and compare them as string :

```
"SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE CAST(u_id as nvarchar(3))=".$loginCode
```

Comment: +1 Nice, that would force MySQL to compare strings.  For a large table, this could hurt performance, since an index on u_id could not be used.  But tbl_user is unlikely to be very large :)

Comment: it returns following error:
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'n varchar(3))=2 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1`

Comment: Appearantly you can't cast to `varchar`.  Try `trim(cast(u_id as nchar(12)))` instead

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tbl_user WHERE TRIM(CAST(u_id AS nchar(3)))=2.0`
Return still return same result